# Considerando um BD que se baseia em ODBC, qual é a função do JDBC neste caso?

Tags: java

Qual o objetivo do JDBC em um bd que se baseia em ODBC?

Comment: bd baseado em ODBC ?

Comment: Cara ODBC e JDBC ambas são formas de se conectar a bancos de dados externos, ou seja o objetivo de ambas é o mesmo

Comment: JDBC = Java Database Connectivity e ODBC = Open Database Connectivity

Comment: Isso tá tipo uma charada: Considerando um BD que se baseia em ODBC, qual é a função...

Answer (score 3):

ODBC é uma interface que não depende de uma linguagem de programação, banco de dados ou sistema operacional específico. Pode ser usado para escrever aplicações que buscam dados de qualquer banco de dados, independente do ambiente que estiver rodando. A maior vantagem de se usar ODBC é como interface entre uma aplicação e um banco de dados é que  quando o banco de dados for alterado a aplicação não precisa ser modificada.

JDBC é uma API para a linguagem Java que a facilita o client a acessar uma base de dados, provendo métodos para buscar e atualizar os dados do banco. JDBC é melhor aplicado para banco de dados orientados a objeto.

Decidindo entre ODBC e JDBC

**Use o ODBC para:**

- Melhor performance para importação e exportação de dados
- Importação e exportações que usem muita memória.

**Use o JDBC para:**

- Plataformas independentes, permitindo trabalhar com qualquer sistema operacional(32 e 64 bits).
- Usar funções já implementadas na interface;
- Trabalhar com tipos complexos de dados como LONG, BLOB, etc.